# Need help creating a style based on several conditions

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF application has a View Model object that has several Boolean properties based on two different `int` properties:

```
public class MyViewModel : ModelBase {

    public int Class { 
        get { return iClass; }
        set {
            iClass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( "Class" );
            OnPropertyChanged( "IsClass1" );
        }
    }
    private int iClass;

    public int Status { 
        get { return iStatus; }
        set {
            iStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( "Status" );
            OnPropertyChanged( "IsStatus1" );
            OnPropertyChanged( "IsStatus2" );
            OnPropertyChanged( "IsStatus3" );
        }
    }
    private int iStatus;

    public bool IsClass1 {
        get { return Class == Class1; }
    }

    public bool IsStatus1 {
        get { return Status == Status1; }
    }

    public bool IsStatus2 {
        get { return Status == Status2; }
    }

    public bool IsStatus3 {
        get { return Status == Status3; }
    }

    // . . .
}
```

I have a `ListBox` in a window that displays these `MyViewModel` objects.  The data for the object contains an image, which is displayed as a thumbnail inside a `Border` control.  The `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties' values depend on some conditions that are derived from the Boolean properties.  In C#, the code for these conditions looks like this:

```
string color = alarm.IsClass1  ? "BorderColor1" :
               alarm.IsStatus1 ? "BorderColor2" :
               alarm.IsStatus2 ? "BorderColor3" :
               alarm.IsStatus3 ? "BorderColor4" :
               "BorderColor5";
Border.SetResourceReference( BorderBrushProperty, color );
Border.BorderThickness = new Thickness( alarm.IsStatus1 || alarm.IsStatus3 ? 4.0 : 2.0 );
```

I want to put this into a `Style` in the XAML for the `DataTemplate` that is used in the `ListBox`:

```
<DataTempate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="5" 
            Height="100"
            Name="Border" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Width="100">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" 
                   Name="AlarmImage" 
                   Source="{Binding Path=Image}" 
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <local:ResponseTimer Expired="Timer_Expired"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              HideIfStatus1="True"
                              IsTabStop="False"
                              MinHeight="10"
                              x:Name="TheTimer"
                              TimeoutPeriod="00:02:30"
                              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<Style TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColor5}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsStatus1}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsStatus3}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4" />
        </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsClass1}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColor1}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsClass1}" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsStatus1}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColor2}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsClass1}" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsStatus2}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColor3}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsClass1}" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsStatus3}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColor4}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you want to have an value or multivalue converter in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view model is supposed to be the model of the view. Therefore, provide it with the correct model for the view that you want. By that I mean keep the complicated logic in the view model and expose it as simple `bool` properties.

```
public bool IsCombinedCondition1 { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
...
public bool IsCombinedConditionN { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Then you can use a simple `DataTrigger` for each combined condition, ordering them with the most important condition at the bottom, as ones declared lower will override ones declared higher in the XAML:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsCombinedCondition1}" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColor1}" />
</DataTrigger>
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsCombinedConditionN}" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BorderColorN}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

You could alternatively use an `enum` just as well. Either way, it's always best to keep the UI as simple as possible and keep the complicated functionality in the view model.